# How to create one XML file from multiple XML files in a directory, using Perl

Tags: xml, perl, perl-module

Hi every one,
Please excuse me if any grammatical mistakes is there.
 I have multiple xml files in one directory, I need to create multiple  XML files into one XML file.example files like this

```
  file1:bvr.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<specification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <details>
 <name>johan</name>
 <address>Langgt 23</address>
  ---more info---
 </details>
</specification>

 file2:kvr.xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <specification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <details>
 <name>venu</name>
 ---more info---
 </details>
 </specification>

   file3:svr.xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <specification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <details>
 <name>kent</name>
 ---more info----
  </details>
  </specification>

  file4:tvr.xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <specification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <definition>
 <name>kent</name>
  ----more info---
  </definition>
  </specification>
```

I need to create one xml file like this.

```
       new.xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<specification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <details>
 <name>johan</name>
 <address>Langgt 23</address>
  --more info--
 </details>

 <details>
 <name>venu</name>
 ---more info----
 </details>

 <details>
 <name>kent</name>
 <address>vadrss 25</address>
 ---more info--
  </details>

   <definition>
 <name>kent</name>
  ----more info----
  </definition>
</specification>
```

I tried like this But I have some problems with this script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
  use warnings;
  use strict;
 use File::Find;
   use XML::LibXML::Reader;
 use Data::Dumper;
  my $Number;

  my $dir="C:/file/sav";
  find(\&wanted, $dir);
  sub wanted() {
       if ( -f and /(\.xml)$/) {# find all the files with a suffix of .xml

  my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new( location =>$_ )
 or die "cannot read file.xml\n";

    while ($reader->nextElement( 'details' ) ){

          $Number = $reader->readOuterXml();

          print "$Number\n";    
             } 

         }
   return;                   
  }
```

but I have two problem in this script

1) I am extracting information from all XML files Having "details" Node element, But in one XML file I have data with some other Node element "definition" I am not extracting that information, What should I do if I want to extract that information and store in the same variable.

2) After extracting all information That is stored in a `$Number` variable, I want to store that `$Number` variable information in one XML file how can I do that one. Please help me.I am very new to perl.

```
                    (or)
```

Is there any other ways to combined all XML files data into one XML file.

After trying your code as you said it gives some more errors

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
  use XML::LibXML;
my @xml_files = glob '*.xml';
my $bigXML = XML::LibXML::Document->new( '1.0', 'UTF-8');
my $aggregated; for my $xml_file ( @xml_files ) {

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file( $xml_file );

my ( $specNode ) = $doc->findnodes( '//Specification' );

  if ( $aggregated ) {
 $aggregated = $specNode;
 }
 else {
 my @details = $specNode->findnodes( './details' );
 $aggregated->addChild( $_ ) foreach @details;
 }
  }
  $bigXML->adoptNode( $aggregated ); 
 $bigXML->toFile( 'aggregated_data.xml' );
```

it giving same error as I asked before `can't call method "findnodes" on an undefined value`, I tried to replce dot with slash in details line also it giving same error.

and if tried to use golb function like this

```
my @xml_files = glob '*dtc.xml';
```

in the above code this time it gives different error like

```
XML::LibXML::Document::adoptNode()-- Node is not a blessed SV reference at line 21
```

I am struggling with these errors because this is very new module for me and also I looked into the that document , every thing is in right format but I cant understand this errors. I am very beginner to this perl , can help me.

Comment: 3 of your 4 files are not valid XML. They have a <shiporder> open tag that appears to be paired with a </specification> closing tag... You should copy/paste rather than (attempt to) retype complicated code or data.

Comment: @tadmc sorry for that now i edited it, its my typing mistake.

Comment: @verendra : I've updated the code now, sorry for the delay in response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thank you for posting your effort here and for stating what you ultimately want to do, which is combine all XMLs into a single file.

To address the needs of the problem :

1. `use strict; use warnings;`

   To catch silly mistakes and enforce good error handling
2. `use XML::LibXML;`

   Use your parser
3. `my @xml_files = glob '*.xml';`

   Find all XML files in your directory
4. `my $bigXML = XML::LibXML::Document->new( '1.0', 'UTF-8');`

   Instantiate big XML where all nodes will be stored.
5. Loop over each file, get the  node and push the  node into an aggregated  node

   my $aggregated;
   for my $xml_file ( @xml_files ) {

   ```
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file( $xml_file );

   my ( $specNode ) = $doc->findnodes( '//specification' );

   if ( ! $aggregated ) {        # Initialize if doesn't exist

       $aggregated = $specNode;
   }

   else {                        # Add more <details>

       my @details = $specNode->findnodes( './details' );
       $aggregated->addChild( $_ ) foreach @details;
   }
   ```

   }
6. Add the `$aggregated` node to the `$bigXML` document and print:

   `$bigXML->addChild( $aggregated );
   $bigXML->toFile( 'aggregated_data.xml' );`

Comment: @Ziad Thanks for your reply and When I try your code I am getting error on line 17 (In else condition), " Can't call method "findnodes" on an undefined value at c:\file\sav\xml.pl. And one more question you used glob function to find all .xml files, It gives all xml files in current working directory I think, what can I do if .xml files In one folder in the current working directory, because in current working directory I have some other xml files I don't want to extract that ones.

Comment: @verendra : Change the `glob` argument to filter out the unwanted XMLs. Judging by your example, it'll be something like `my @xml_files = glob '*vr.xml';`. I've updated the `findnodes` argument to `//specification`, that should fix your undefined issue.

Comment: sorry for asking once again because I didn't see this type of errors before, After modification according to your suggestion it gives two errors , I explained clearly in my question. Can you have a look at and please help me.

Comment: I think I know why it's not working but don't have the time to investigate. I hope to get back by tomorrow