# How to eliminate tag names in xml file using perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have multiple XML files in a folder,so I written script like this to combine into one xml file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
use Carp;
use File::Find;
use File::Spec::Functions qw( canonpath );
use XML::LibXML::Reader;
use Digest::MD5 'md5';

if ( @ARGV == 0 ) {
push @ARGV, "c:/main/work";
warn "Using default path $ARGV[0]\n  Usage: $0  path ...\n";
}

open( my $allxml, '>', "all_xml_contents.combined.xml" )
 or die "can't open output xml file for writing: $!\n";
print $allxml '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>',
"\n<Shiporder xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n";
 my %shipto_md5;
find(
sub {
return unless ( /(_stc\.xml)$/ and -f );
extract_information();
return;
 },
@ARGV
);

print $allxml "</Shiporder>\n";

sub extract_information {
my $path = $_;
 if ( my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new( location => $path )) {
while ( $reader->nextElement( 'data' )) {
    my $elem = $reader->readOuterXml();
    my $md5 = md5( $elem );
    print $allxml $reader->readOuterXml() unless ( $shipto_md5{$md5}++ );
 }
 }
return;
}
```

It printing all xml files into one xml like this.

```
 all_xml.combined.xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<student specification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <student>
<name>johan</name>
 </student>

<student>
<name>benny</name>
</student>

 <student>
<name>kent</name>
 </student>

 </student specification>
```

but I have one more node information in one xml file, i tried to extract that information like this in while loop.

```
    $reader->nextElement( 'details' );
     $information = $reader->readInnerXml();
```

but how can i add this information to output file, please help me with this problem.

Comment: This is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/8187077/133939

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three obvious points.

1. You're loading the XML::LibXML module but not making any use of it.
2. The problematic XML declaration is always the first line of the input files. So why not just skip the first line?
3. The file you will end up with will not be valid XML. An XML document needs a single root element. So you'll need to create another element (perhaps <students>) that surrounds all of the data from the other files.

Comment: I can't understand what you said can you help how to overcome this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can make it clearer. What didn't you understand?

Comment: I eliminate my problem now I am generating new xml file with one tag name under that I am storing all xml files.I modified my script have a look at my new script , but in this i have one more problem can you help with that please.

Answer (score 2):

Will it be possible for you to switch to [XML::Twig](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aTwig)? It provides excellent way of handling the tags.

Probably you need something like

```
 my $twig=XML::Twig->new(   
    twig_handlers => 
      { 
        **student with specification** => sub { $_->delete;       },  # remove hidden elements
      },
```

You need to modify the student with specification to work for you. Sorry, I don't have much time, otherwise I would have written complete code.

Comment: I am very new to perl language after some suggestions I gone through XML::LibXML and I written like this it takes so much time for me ,Every thing is working you know only the problem. If now I want to shift to XML::Twig then it takes for me some more time and I need to modify entire code, can you help me please how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that does it using DOMDocument()

Over all, 
1) Create a parent document from a string  or similar
2) Load each file, import, and append
3) Save the results.

It's usually better in XML programming to use XML parser functions, rather than string manipulation.

Good luck.

```
function loadXMLString( $strXML ) {
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true; 
    $xmlDoc->loadXML( $strXML );
    return $xmlDoc;
}

function loadXMLFile( $strFileName, $defaultXML=null ) {
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    if( file_exists( $strFileName )  ){
        $xmlDoc->load( $strFileName );
    } else {
        if( $defaultXML == null  ) {
            throw new Exception( "Cannot locate file: " . $strFileName . " no default specified." );
        } else {
            // create it, if default XML is supplied
            return $this->loadXMLString( $defaultXML );
        } 
    }
    return $xmlDoc;
}


$xmlMain = loadXMLString( "<xmlparent/>" );

$xmlChild = loadXMLFile( "test1.xml" );
$ndTemp = $xmlMain->importNode( $xmlChild->documentElement, true );
$xmlMain->documentElement->appendChild( $ndTemp );

$xmlChild = loadXMLFile( "test2.xml" );
$ndTemp = $xmlMain->importNode( $xmlChild->documentElement, true );
$xmlMain->documentElement->appendChild( $ndTemp );

$xmlMain->save( "all.xml" );
```

Comment: Which module you used , I can't understand properly your concept can you give some more detailed explanation. If I have several XML files also I need to write like this or I need to iterate any loop.

Comment: I use the PHP DOMDocument class, see http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: You can use this in a loop too.  First, load the $xmlMain, then start your loop through the folder, loading a new $xmlChild for each file, and appending to $xmlMain.  Finally, after your loop compeletes, save $xmlMain